# Windbg - how to dump non-local variables values

Tags: debugging, windbg, dump

I see a simple `dv` does not dump non-local variables values (e.g member variables - member fields of a class)

Also `dt` will not work.. I am new to windbg so I assume I am just missing a command.

Or do I need to change some settings so `dv` would dump the variable I need regardless of scope?

Comment: I wonder why `dt` does not work. How do you use it?

Comment: Never mind All i needed to do is `dt this`

Comment: I was trying to do `dt m_membervar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
dt this m_membervar
```

OR add a period

```
dt this m_membervar.
```

OR

```
dt /r1 this
```